Create newtcolorbox with visual look as old paper
In my MNWE code, you can see that i try to create tcolorbox environment with decoration. In summary, the frame code in MNWE draws a jagged, irregular rectangular frame around the tcolorbox with a light yellow fill and a blurred shadow effect. The frame is created by connecting the corners of the box and applying the specified decorations and effects.
  frame code={
    \draw[
      decorate, 
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}, 
      fill=yellow!20, 
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  },

It works well until the box should break across pages. You can see on the figure below that color is changed unexpectedly to gray and the jagged decoration disappears. I thought the breakable option would fix it but unfortunately it doesn't work. I try to study the manual tcolorbox, but I'm clueless. My guess is that the problem must be in the frame code part.

MNWE:
 \documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  twocolumn,
  open=any, 
  titlepage=false, 
  chapterprefix=on
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[    
    showframe=true,
    verbose=true,                 % displays the parameter results on the terminal
    paperwidth  = 447pt,          % 157.10mm 
    paperheight = 595pt,          % 209.12mm 
    % landscape,                  %
    includehead, includefoot,     % include the head and foot into total body
    scale=1.0,                    %
    nomarginpar,                  % shrinks spaces for marginal notes to 0pt,
                                  % \marginparwidth=0pt and \marginparwidth=0pt
    left=3pt, right=3pt,          % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    top=0pt, bottom=11pt,         % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    textwidth=441pt,              % Nastaví šířku textové oblasti na 441 bodů
    textheight=562pt,             % Nastaví výšku textové oblasti na 562 bodů; upravte podle potřeby
    headsep=0pt,                  % Vzdálenost mezi záhlavím a textem
    headheight=12pt,              % At least 11.0pt needed!! 
    showframe=false,              %
    nofoot,                       % noheadfoot=true, 
    heightrounded,                % better use it
]{geometry} 

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shadows.blur}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Add this line to include the lipsum package

\newtcolorbox{luatikzcitbox}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  opacityback=0.1,
  % colframe=black,
  rounded corners,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  % internal margins text to frame
  left=4mm,
  right=4mm,
  top=2mm,
  bottom=2mm,
  % external marigns to surroundings
  before skip=3mm,
  after skip=3mm,
  left skip=1mm,
  right skip=2.5mm,
  % width=\linewidth,
  % boxsep=2mm,
  frame code={
    \draw[
      decorate, 
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}, 
      fill=yellow!20, 
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  },
}

\begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \begin{luatikzcitbox}
   \blindtext
 \end{luatikzcitbox}
 \blindtext
 \begin{luatikzcitbox}
  \blindtext
  \blindtext
\end{luatikzcitbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[right skip=2cm,left skip=1cm,
  colframe=red!50!white]
  This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


you can't break the picture. you need to provide it in pieces for a breakable box, I think. but you will need fixed start/end points for the joins if they are to match up.

If you accept that frame is random, you could use same code to define first ,middle and last part in the breakable boxes. However, the start/end points won't match up:
 \documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  twocolumn,
  open=any, 
  titlepage=false, 
  chapterprefix=on
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    verbose=true,                 % displays the parameter results on the terminal
    paperwidth  = 447pt,          % 157.10mm 
    paperheight = 595pt,          % 209.12mm 
    % landscape,                  %
    includehead, includefoot,     % include the head and foot into total body
    scale=1.0,                    %
    nomarginpar,                  % shrinks spaces for marginal notes to 0pt,
                                  % \marginparwidth=0pt and \marginparwidth=0pt
    %left=3pt, right=3pt,          % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    %top=0pt, bottom=11pt,         % Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    textwidth=441pt,              % Nastaví šířku textové oblasti na 441 bodů
    textheight=562pt,             % Nastaví výšku textové oblasti na 562 bodů; upravte podle potřeby
    headsep=0pt,                  % Vzdálenost mezi záhlavím a textem
    headheight=12pt,              % At least 11.0pt needed!! 
    %showframe=false,              %
    nofoot,                       % noheadfoot=true, 
    heightrounded,                % better use it
]{geometry} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shadows.blur}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{luatikzcitbox}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colframe=yellow!20,
  frame style={draw,line width=1pt},
  % internal margins text to frame (These was default)
  %left=4mm,
  %right=4mm,
  %top=2mm,
  %bottom=2mm,
  % external marigns to surroundings
  before skip=3mm,
  after skip=3mm,
  left skip=1mm,
  right skip=2.5mm,
  % width=\linewidth,
  % boxsep=2mm,
  watermark color=red!20,
  watermark text=unbroken,
  frame code={
    \path[
      tcb fill frame,
      decorate,
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt},
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  },
  interior empty,
  skin first is subskin of={emptyfirst}{%
  watermark text=first,
  frame code={
    \path[
      tcb fill frame,
      decorate,
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt},
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  }
 },
 skin middle is subskin of={emptymiddle}{%
  watermark text=middle,
  frame code={
    \path[
      tcb fill frame,
      decorate,
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt},
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  }
 },
 skin last is subskin of={emptylast}{%
 watermark text=last,
 frame code={
    \path[
      tcb fill frame,
      decorate,
      decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt},
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] 
    (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
  }
 }
}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{luatikzcitbox}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{luatikzcitbox}
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{luatikzcitbox}
 \lipsum[1-5]
 \end{luatikzcitbox}
\end{document}



I didn't think of that solution. What did you do? Is this method described in tcolorbox?

@JardaFait Yes, check the https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf P.273
